# Same activity but different layouts?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm kind of new to android java so I started to create a Music Player app just to learn and practice. The main thing was to control the same MediaPlayer from 2 different activities (In MainActivity there's a listview with the music files and PlayerActivity has the MediaPlayer). I tried to use public voids like:

```
PlayerActivity pa = new PlayerActivity();

//button onClick
pa.songPlay();
```

and it kind of worked at first but then a lot of errors occurred when using contexts and MediaPlayer.create(), so I started to look for another way to do this but found none so far. Is there a way to make 2 different layouts with a shared element, and with the same class?

For a better explanation:

MainActivity:
[image: MainActivity]

PlayerActivity:
[image: PlayerActivity]

And fuse them like:
[image: Fused layout]

Comment: code you media player in service class and bind your service in different activity
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-android/tree/master/audioplayerexample
it will help remove IMA ads code

Comment: `The main thing was to control the same MediaPlayer from 2 different activities` only one activity is ever active at a time, so sounds like you might be doing something wrong

Comment: @a_local_nobody Well I could hear and control the music in both activities (in the emulator, don't know if its the same on a real device), but there were errors with the "Next song" button (nextbut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I'm answering my own question because I didn't know that `FrameLayouts` exist, but since I found them I can put two different layouts into the same space and just set the `visibility` to `VISIBLE` or `GONE` whenever I want to switch between them